# Ruby on Rails 4: New action in modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the index view I have a list of my models and `"Create new"` button. When user clicks on the button a modal form should be presented with one field: name of the model - the only field that required to create a model. When the user enters the name and click submit button the model get saved and edit view is displayed as a normal page ( with all fields from model available for editing).

How to achieve this? I have tried to build a new object in the index action:

```
  def index
    @my_models = MyModel.all
    @new_model = MyModel.build
  end
```

but that did not work (I was getting missing template error although without `@new_model` the index was displayed without problems)

Another question is how to render the form? Should I put the form into `new.html.erb` file
and then include `<%= render 'new' %>` in the body of the modal? (I am using Bootstrap 3.1 to create the modal itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
@my_model = MyModel.new
```

and call

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

which uses @my_model.

Comment: Where should I put `<%= render 'form' %>`? Is it form that will be shown in popup?

Comment: In your index view, wrapped in a bootstrap modal.